# How to make Ruffle Go Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, ruffle

I have a website that has a lot of games including Flash.
Im using Ruffle Emulator to emulate those games.
I have a fullscreen button thats supposed to go in Fullscreen but its not.

I have tried to use this code but it does not work

```
  // Get the Ruffle player element 
  const ruffle = window.RufflePlayer.newest();

  if (ruffle.fullscreenEnabled) {
    ruffle.enterFullscreen();
    alert("Press ESC to exit fullscreen.");
  } else {
    alert("Fullscreen is not supported.");
  }
```

If you could help me I would appreaciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When does that code run? Before your button press or after it? Or every time the button is pressed?

Comment: That code runs like this, The user clicks the button then it does some other logic , then calls this function to make it Fullscreen, that logic is to check mainly the game type.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show all that code. From the current question, it's not even clear that the snippet is part of a function.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.